# GParted doesn't recognize the unallocated partition

Tags: linux, windows-11, gparted, dualboot, pop-os

I'm trying to set up a dual boot on my machine with Windows 11 and Pop!_OS. In Windows, I've allocated a space for the Linux system, but during installation, the unallocated space doesn't appear in the disk partitions. In GParted, I can't create a new partition using the space I set aside.

[Disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1fyT.jpg)

[GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uguj1.jpg)

Comment: Make sure POP OS recognizes UEFI, Secured Boot, and TPM V2.  If not (and I do not think all are compatible), what you want will not work.  Set POP OS up as a virtual machine and that will work.

Comment: Disk `sda` is formatted as zfs, but the [GParted Features page](https://gparted.org/features.php) shows that zfs support is very partial. I suggest using another app or another disk format.

Comment: A shot in the dark: I don't know zfs, but in general it's possible to have a signature of a filesystem and a partition table. If the disk was used as zfs without partitioning and if someone (or something) managed to create the partition table and the filesystem without fully erasing some signature of zfs, and *if GParted checks for zfs first*, then you will see zfs in GParted. *I don't know* if this is what happens. `file -skr /dev/sda` may show something. If I'm right, a *careful* use of `wipefs -t` may help.